# error using frequncycounter library in arduino mega

Tags: arduino, counter, frequency

[image]

dear 
i wrote this code to calculate wind speed from anemometer
 below the error message

> windspeedcode2:15: error: 'FreqCount' is not a class, namespace, or
>   enumeration
>
> FreqCount::f_comp= 8;             // Set compensation to 12
>
> ^
>
> windspeedcode2:16: error: 'FreqCount' is not a class, namespace, or
>   enumeration
>
> FreqCount::start(100);            // Start counting with gatetime of
>   100ms
>
> ^
>
> windspeedcode2:17: error: 'FreqCounter' has not been declared
>
> while (FreqCounter::f_ready == 0)         // wait until counter
>   ready
>
> ```
>      ^
> ```
>
> windspeedcode2:19: error: 'FreqCount' is not a class, namespace, or
>   enumeration
>
> freq=FreqCount::f_freq;//read frequency value
>
> ```
>    ^
> ```
>
> exit status 1 'FreqCount' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`::` is the scope resolution operator for defining the same function outside the class

`.` is the dot operator used to call a member function (or member variable) on a object.

An example would be (assuming a instance named FreqCount exist in you library header): `FreqCount.f_comp= 8;`

Only if `f_comp` is a `static` class member variable can it be accessed is you called it: `FreqCount::f_comp= 8;` But that is unlikely for a library.

So what is in your header and where does the library come from?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help the problem has been solved by downloading another library 
as shown in picture[image]